# warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/stash 2

Tags: git

I see that there are other issues covering this topic but it also seems rather sensitive. I don't want to delete any data so I want to make sure that I fix this the correct way. I'm getting this error when ever I try to autocomplete anything with git.

#### ERROR:

```
warning: ignoring ref with broken name refs/stash 2
```

Does anybody know what is going wrong here and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's not clear to me is what *created* these incorrect / broken reference names.

To fix it, you can *delete* them:

```
git update-ref -d 'refs/stash 2'
```

However, note that whatever *made* them might be expecting them to be useful (they're not) and to protect various internal Git objects (they may not, because some parts of Git reject them as invalid).

They are in fact invalid; see [the `git check-ref-format` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html) for details.  The `git update-ref` command refuses to *create* the bad references, so (again) it's not clear what *made* them.  (Probably evil software that writes directly into `.git`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the followings:

1. `git fetch --all --prune`
   This will fetch all your **remotes** and should fix the "broken" remote. The `--prune` will remote from your local repository all the removed content from the remote,
2. `git fsck --full`
   !!! be careful with this one, This command will verify that all your git objects are not damaged and you should get a list of the dangling ones.
   As a side effect, it will run `git gc` and will clean your unused data.

Comment: So be kind and vote :-)

Comment: the +1 came from me :)